# Using a dictionary with a while-loop

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

Im trying to use a dictionary key in the while-loops condition statement, the program won't recognize any input as 'correct'

```
class Gymnast_room(KeyCode):    
    def enter(self):
        print "This is the gymnastics room, we got foam pits and rings!"
        print "Before you can enter, you have to enter the code"
        guess = int(raw_input('What is the code? >>'))

        passcodes = {'Gymnast_code': 1234,
        'Powerlifting_code': 1234
        }
        while guess != passcodes['Gymnast_code']:
            guess = int(raw_input('What is the code? >>'))
            if guess == passcodes['Gymnast_code']:
                print "Correct!"
                return Powerlifting_room()
            else:
                print "Incorrect!"
```

Comment: What you've shown us [works perfectly for me](http://ideone.com/55RFSC). I deduce that the problem is what you *haven't* shown. Please reduce your original program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Copy-paste that small, complete program into your question, along with your expected and actual results. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't ask for the `guess` before the loop, because if the answer is correct - it won't enter the loop at all. Replace:

```
guess = int(raw_input('What is the code? >>'))
```

with:

```
guess = None
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I'll keep 'None' in mind for the future, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def enter(self):
    print "This is the gymnastics room, we got foam pits and rings!"
    print "Before you can enter, you have to enter the code"
    guess = int(raw_input('What is the code? >>'))

    passcodes = {'Gymnast_code': 1234,
    'Powerlifting_code': 1234
    }
    while guess != passcodes['Gymnast_code']:
        print "Incorrect!"
        guess = int(raw_input('What is the code? >>'))

    print "Correct!"
    return Powerlifting_room()
```

Comment: @Ivella Thanks this works as a great alternative, makes sense now. I was only allowing the while-loop to run if the user had an incorrect answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you're saying "while the passcodes not the gymnast code, check if it's the business code", because by the time you get here, it'll never go inside the while-loop and never finish

```
   while guess != passcodes['Gymnast_code']:
        guess = int(raw_input('What is the code? >>'))
        if guess == passcodes['Gymnast_code']:
            print "Correct!"
            return Powerlifting_room()
        else:
            print "Incorrect!"
```

Comment: thank you I understand now. I wasn't even allowing the while-loop to be entered. Thanks again!